# Is there a way to turn off auto-complete on an input-field using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to turn off auto-complete on an input-field using jQuery?

Like this:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" />
```

Comment: `$("input[type=text]").attr("autocomplete", "off");`

Comment: @TEG: if you're answering the question, put it in an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"autocomplete" isn't a standard attribute.  Yes it's implemented, but it's not proper XHTML.

Do you have to do it client-side?  Can you make changes on the server-side if necessary?

Comment: I know it isn't standard XHTML, but I need for validation purposes. The reason why I need to add it with jQuery is due to the fact that the developers are using Struts and it doesn't allow you to put autocomplete="off" on as an attribute on the Struts html-tag.

Answer (score 6):

```
$(':text').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input#id').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
```

You can also use a common class to turn off a group of fields. There are a few ways to do it though as you'll see from the answers.

Comment: Forgive me, already edited it. Was in the midst of working with an array and slipped.

Comment: The same can be done with your query.

       `$('#id').attr('autocomplete', 'off');`

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#id').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
```

Answer (score 2):

For any text field, you could do this.

```
$("input[type=text]").attr("autocomplete", "off");
```

Hope this helps!